# can I be shown how to fix my syntax error : "unexpected token var line 65"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

(1:) I am writing a webhook script. (2:) Using "google sheets" and it's script editor. It is not liking how I used the below syntax.

```
`function sendMessage(message, channel)
 {
     if(webhooks(channel))
     var url = webhooks[channel];
     else {
     Logger.log("Error Sending Message to Channel " + channel);
     return "NoStoredWebhookException";
 }
  
     var payload = JSON.stringify({content: message});

     Logger.log(options, null, 2);
       UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1069728124704653413/_h9KQdxqenUWGSSE5xR91QgBU28bdcUcY2yGslu83KezXvUTEv7BlJzvYo-mVTBv5_ye", options);

     var webhooks = {
     test: "Obtain a webhook for the channel you'd like and put it here."

     var params = {
     headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
     method: "POST",
     payload: payload,
     muteHttpExceptions: true
     };
 
     var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
     Logger.log(res.getContentText());
 }`
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the second brace on the webhooks object

```js
var webhooks = {
     test: "Obtain a webhook for the channel you'd like and put it here."
}
```